# Attributes on a derived type not being deserialized in a WCF client even though KnownType is used

Tags: wcf, datacontract, known-types

I have the following types:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}

[DataContract]
public class Configuration
{
    [DataMember]
    public MyEnum MyValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Credentials CredentialValues { get; set; }
}

[DataContract, KnownType(typeof(CustomCredentials))]
public class Credentials 
{

}

[DataContract]
public class CustomCredentials : Credentials 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

And on my service interface, I have a function that returns an instance of `Configuration` with its `CredentialValues` property set to a fully populated instance of `CustomCredentials`. I receive no errors from the client or the server, but while the data is being property serialized on the server and received by the client, the properties on `CustomCredentials` never have a value. What do I need to change here in order to have these properties properly deserialized on the client?

For reference, the connection between client and server is made with a `DuplexChannelFactory` over a `NetTcpBinding` using a data/service contract project that is shared by the client and service applications (the service is self-hosted), so there are no service proxy types that could need to be regenerated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this code to the Contracts project along with your DataContracts.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.platinumray.com/duplex", SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IService1Callback))]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void GetData();
}

public interface IService1Callback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SetData(Configuration config);
}
```

Created the service.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void GetData()
    {
        var x = new Configuration()
        {
            MyValue = MyEnum.Value1,
            CredentialValues = new CustomCredentials { Property1 = "Something", Property2 = "Something else" }
        };
        OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IService1Callback>().SetData(x);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost( typeof(Service1), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:6789") }))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new NetTcpBinding(), "Service1");
            host.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Created the client.

```
public class CallbackHandler : IService1Callback
{
    public void SetData(Configuration config)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(config.CredentialValues.GetType().Name);
        Console.WriteLine(((CustomCredentials)config.CredentialValues).Property1);
        Console.WriteLine(((CustomCredentials)config.CredentialValues).Property2);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Setup the client
        var callbacks = new CallbackHandler();
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:6789/Service1"));
        using (var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService1>(callbacks, new NetTcpBinding(), endpoint))
        {
            var client = factory.CreateChannel();
            client.GetData();
            Console.ReadLine();
            factory.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs the following as expected:

> ```
> CustomCredentials
> Something
> Something else
> ```

So this actually worked without modifying any of your data contracts... The same results if I revert to a twoway operation and just return `Configuration` directly without using the callback.

Also tried making Credentials abstract but could not replicate your problem.

Have I missed something?

Comment: I'm accepting and awarding the bounty because this turned out to be a bone-headed error on my part that is completely unrelated to WCF. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Having made more than my shares of such errors in the past, I suspected this might be the case. Glad it's all sorted anyway. Regards, A Fellow Bonehead.